# Redirect www.*.domain.com to *.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like some help with Apache redirect.
My Virtual Hosts file is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
ServerName app.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com www.*.example.com
....
```

I would like for each request with `www.*.example.com` to redirect to `*.example.com`

For example:

```
www.subdomain1.example.com -> subdomain1.example.com
www.subdomain5.example.com -> subdomain5.example.com
```

Requests like:

```
subdomain99.example.com
```

should remain as they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```